# Determining the inequality sign in a complex mapping

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The question reads for the mapping $$ f(z) = \frac{z-i}{z+i} $$Find the image of $$ Im(z)>0  $$ where  z is a complex number.

I've solved the shape of the mapping (circle of radius 1 centered at origin I believe) by substituting y=0 into the mapping and doing the algebra.

My question is, how do I determine if the inequality will be the area inside or outside the circle? The lectures went through a similar problem and they solved it by seeing what z=0 maps to but it wasn't really explained. What does knowing what value z=0 maps to tell you about the mapping?

Comment: Take a complex number inside the circle and substitute in $f(z)$ and simplify. Observe the sign of the imaginary part of your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [Cayley transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform#Conformal_map), which maps the upper half plane conformally onto the unit disc. The reason is explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705000/conformal-maps-from-the-upper-half-plane-to-the-unit-disc-has-the-form).