# Complex bilinear transformation.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $H=\{z=z+iy\in\mathbb{C}:y>0\}$ be the upper half plane and $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$ be the open unit disc. Suppose that $f$ is a Mobius transformation, which maps $H$ conformally onto $D.$ Suppose that $f(2i)=0.$ Pick the correct statement from below.

$1. f$ has a simple pole at $z=-2i.$

$2. f$ satisfy $f(i)\overline{f(-i)}=1.$

$3. f$ has an essential singularity at $z=-2i.$

$4. |f(2+2i)|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}.$

I tried it as i consider the required transformation as $f(z)=\frac{z-2i}{z+2i}.$ So according to me correct options are $1$st, $2$nd and $4$th. But my method is very particular. Please suggest me most general way to handle this problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You transformation has a simple pole at $-2i$ not $2i$.

Comment: yes i edited it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T(z)=e^{i\theta}\frac{z-z_0}{z-\bar{z}_0}$ is the most general transformation mapping the upper half plane to the unit circle, provided $z_0$ is in the upper half plane. ([Link on MSE to the proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705000/conformal-maps-from-the-upper-half-plane-to-the-unit-disc-has-the-form?rq=1))

$$T(2i)=0 \Rightarrow 2i-z_0=0 \Rightarrow z_0=2i$$
So :
$$T(z)=e^{i\theta}\frac{z-2i}{z+2i}$$

Can you go from there ?

Comment: yes sir...thanks a lot...