# How to combine these transformations into a single Mobius transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

So I have these four transformations given by:
$$z \mapsto z - \frac i 2$$

$$z \mapsto -z $$

$$z \mapsto \frac{z-i}{z+i}$$

$$z \mapsto z+1 $$

And I need to combine them into a single transformation. But every way I tried seems to get a different answer to the solution given.

The solution given was

$$z \mapsto \frac{4z-2i}{2z-3i}$$

Comment: Hi, you could please tell us what the official solution is, and could you please write out / sketch what you've done, so that we can compare?

Comment: Also, are you aware that you can represent Mobius transformations as matrices? Composition of Mobius transformations is the same as multiplying the corresponding matrices.

Comment: @KennyWong sorted you out brother

Comment: @Daniel McEnroy I imagine that "sorted you out brother" has a meaning for KennieWong to whom it is addressed, but with my limited knowledge of English idiosyncrasies, it doesn't make sense. Could you say what this expression means ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Daniel McEnroy Can you answer my question ? I am serious, I want to better my knowledge of English, which is not my mother language as you can guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$z \mapsto z - \frac i 2 = \frac{2z - i}{2} = \frac{2z + (-i)}{0z + 2} \implies \begin{pmatrix}2 &-i \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$

$$z \mapsto -z = \frac{-1z + 0}{0z + 1} \implies \begin{pmatrix}-1 &0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$z \mapsto \frac{z-i}{z+i} = \frac{1z + (-i)}{1z + i} \implies \begin{pmatrix}1 &-i \\ 1 & i\end{pmatrix}$$

$$z \mapsto z+1 = \frac{1z + 1}{0z + 1} \implies \begin{pmatrix}1 &1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Multiply the matrices together (in the reverse order as stated):

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 &1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 &-i \\ 1 & i\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-1 &0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2 &-i \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-4 &2i \\ -2 & 3i\end{pmatrix}$$

Which corresponds to a translation of $\frac{-4z + 2i}{-2z + 3i} = \frac{4z - 2i}{2z - 3i}$, which matches your result.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(z) = \begin{pmatrix}a &b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix} = \frac{az + b}{cz + d},~ z\rightarrow -z \\
\frac{a(-z) + b}{c(-z) + d} = \frac{-az + b}{-cz + d} = 
\begin{pmatrix} -a & b \\ -c & d\end{pmatrix}$$ so our transformation can be found by linear algebra to be 
$$\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\times \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-a & b\\ -c & d\end{pmatrix}$$ So the $z\rightarrow -z$ transform is given by the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Since matrix multiplication represents such a transform, and matrix multiplication is associative, if we know all our transforms, then we can simply find the total transform by the resulting matrix product. Note that since ***in general matrix multiplication is not commutative, the order in which we apply our transforms is important.***

Comment: See I did this but didn't get to the same answer as in the solutions

Comment: @DanielMcElroy The answer depends on what **order** you compose the transformations. If you write the matrices from right to left, then you get the answer in your book.

Comment: @KennyWong Oh right. I was applying the matrices the wrong way. Also, could I ask you a side questions. You know when mapping the Upper half of the plane to the unit disk you do (z-a)/(z-a*) where a* is the conjugate of a. Can you choose any value for a?

Comment: @DanielMcElroy I don't remember - it's been ages since I've done this stuff. But see this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705000/conformal-maps-from-the-upper-half-plane-to-the-unit-disc-has-the-form

Comment: All right, I understand.