# Conformal map and upper-half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers, conformal-geometry

Let $$V := \left \{  z: \Im(z) > 0  \right \} $$ be the upper half-plane. For $a \in V$ we define 
$$h_{a}(z) = \frac{z-a}{z-\bar{a}} $$ for $ z \neq \bar{a}$.

So that $h_{a}$ is a conformal map $V \rightarrow D(0,1)$. 
Let now $f: D(0,1) \rightarrow V$ be a conformal function such that $f(0)=a$. Show that there is a complex number $c$ with $|c|=1$ such that 
$$f(z) = \frac{ac-\bar{a}z}{c-z} $$ for all $z \in D(0,1)$.

It says also we should consider the function $ f \circ h_{a}^{-1} $  and find a general expression for conformal maps $ V \rightarrow V$.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to show that there is such number $c$

Comment: Your question would be improved if you would [include your own work](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) on this problem, as mentioned in [these guidelines for how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Maybe a similar question:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/705000/515871